# Git branch have diverged

Tags: git

I made a `tracking-branch` on `dev-26` branch (see below), using SourceTree, from my organization's Bitbucket account. Here's how roughly my local and remote repositories look like:

```
$ git branch
  master
* dev-26

$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD
  origin/master
  origin/dev-1
  origin/dev-2
  origin/dev-26
```

I committed changes on **Friday 6/17** on my local `dev-26` branch. Since then, I've done `git pull` several times to `fetch` and `merge` changes from `origin/dev-26` onto my local `dev-26` branch. However, I've never pushed my changes.

For some reason, when I do `git status`, I get the following message:

```
On branch dev-26
Your branch and 'origin/dev-26' have diverged,
and have 1053 and 295 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Subsequently, when I do `git pull`, I get a lot of conflict error messages. At this point, I'm lost and just want to discard whatever changes I made on **Friday 6/17** and pull whatever is currently on `origin/dev-26`

So, I did `git reset --hard` on the last commit on **Thursday 6/16** and hoping when I do `git pull`, it will sync up my local `dev-26` branch with `origin/dev26` branch. However, I kept getting the same message (regardless how far back I reset my branch to):

```
On branch dev-26
Your branch and 'origin/dev-26' have diverged,
and have 1053 and 295 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I think I might have screwed up somewhere. Can somebody help me debug/ explain what's going on and/or find an answer to discard changes I made on **Friday 6/17** and just sync my local `dev-26` with `origin/dev-26`?

Comment: Possible explanations for the original problem: (1) these have really diverged in a conflicting way, (2) someone did a force-push at some point.  (FWIW, these commit counts are **crazy** high for single (feature?) branches.)

Comment: I also don't understand why these commit counts are so high @OliverCharlesworth. Anyway, since all these are in my local `dev-26` branch, is there anyway I can drop this local branch without affecting remote `origin/dev-26`? Subsequently, my plan is to create a new `tracking-branch` on `origin/dev-26`

I suppose the command for that is `git branch -d dev-26` and `git branch --track dev-26 origin/dev-26`. Could you verify? I'm just afraid that I accidentally drop `origin/dev-26` branch with these commands

Comment: It doesn't matter if you lose it - it'll be recreated next time you `git fetch`.  But you could just do `git reset --hard origin/dev-26`.

Comment: What version is your Git (`git --version`)?  If it is older than 1.8.2, I know what is happening.

Comment: try `git fetch origin dev-26;git cherry FETCH_HEAD dev-26` to list all the changes you have made in the local but not pushed. Focus on the `+` lines.

Comment: You can see how many commits your local branch is ahead/behind from the upstream branch with `git branch -vv`. And by the way, as I can see, you are ready to discard all the local changes and want to pull down all data from the remote branch. How about creating a new branch, setting the remote branch as the upstream branch then pull down the data: `git checkout -b ldev-26 <first_local_commit_hash>; git branch -u origin/dev-26 git pull;`. Replace <first_local_commit_hash> with the hash (or unique part of it) of the commit from the local history you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this using the following command.

```
git reset --hard origin/dev-26
```